# Edit Scrollbars within Style Tags

Tags: html, css, tags, styles, scrollbar

First of all, my friends and I mostly use Chrome just so everyone knows. I understand that webkits work in Chrome.

Okay, what I need to figure out is how to place the webkit scrollbar edit options into my HTML style tags. I know how to edit scrollbars in a CSS style sheet but I don't not have access to the style sheet. So my only option was to try and make edits using "style=". However, I can't seem to edit my scrollbar and I really like the simple example shown here: http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/.

Is there any way I can do that within the tag?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it is not possible.

Because you can apply `style=` to existing elements in the HTML file (although it is not recommended and this programming habit being deprecated) but `::-webkit-scrollbar` and others are `psuedo-elements` which you can not declare in HTML. So you can not style scrollbars from your HTML file. :-(

But if anyone knows any workaround then I will be happy to know it. :-)

Comment: I figured that was my problem but I too was hoping maybe someone knew a work-around or better knew webkit... Or something. XD And I know editing CSS within "style=" isn't recommended but with this website, I don't really have a choice. Besides, the website is kind of set up oto allow such edits which is great!

As for a potential solution, guess we'll keep our fingers crossed. :D